# Pool heater hook up

Tags: electrical, subpanel, pool

The main panel in my house is 200 amp. I installed a 100 amp subpanel in my garage. Can I put a double-pole 50 amp breaker in my 100 amp subpanel for a pool heater?

Comment: Double 50 amp pole

Comment: Short answer: Probably. Long answer: Need to know the specifics of the garage subpanel. Model, # of spaces available, etc. Picture is worth 1,000 words.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the subpanel? Do you know how much load it's feeding already?

Comment: Cat no  homc20u 100c seriess01 type1

Comment: I don't know much about it has 7 20amp breakers it has 20 spots

Comment: How can put pics on here